# What are the advantages of using a Machine Learning (NN) method instead of regression model in survival analysis?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, survival

Suppose that I have a sample of survival times $t_1,...,t_n$, censoring indicators $d_i = I(t_i < C)$, and covariates $x_i\in{\mathbb R}^P$. Suppose that

1. I have a flexible parametric regression model based on splines, including time dependent effects, and all that show.
2. I can train a neural network based on recent developments on the literature.

Assuming that the computational cost of both approaches is the same.

**Question**: What advantages learning a Neural Network would bring compared to the flexible parametric regression model?

Comment: There's a big disadvantage of typically poor interpretability with neural networks. What types of "advantages" are you expecting?

Comment: @EdM Interesting points. I was expecting something like "better prediction", "more flexibility", or something along those lines; but I did not want to bias the answers. I have seen many many papers in this topic in recent years, but they do not seem to discuss clear advantages. Those papers mostly focused on the "novelty", where novelty means, it has not been done this way.

Comment: I think it is almost impossible to directly compare NN models with parametric models.  Would be great if we could.

Answer (score 2):

The neural net will pick up also interaction effects, unlike your Cox model with (one-dimensional) splines. However, you will need a very large sample size to beat a well built additive Cox model in terms of predictive performance. Furthermore, working with neural nets requires a lot of practical experience (so many things can go wrong) and a bullet proof validation strategy.

If you really want to sacrifice additivity, then I'd suggest to start with a survival random forest. There, you will also have to work with a clean validation strategy, but it is much easier.

Comment: Why would the Cox model not be able to include interactions?

Comment: It is of course, but the OP does not seem to use them. If you start adding many tensor product splines, then your Cox model will also have many parameters, interpretation starts to get complicated and you will need a clean validation strategy...